# vue.component vs import within component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have setup a vue2 library using vue-cli. This library has a lot of components and the following index.ts (example):

```js
import MyComponent1 from './components/MyComponent1.vue';
import MyComponent2 from './components/MyComponent2.vue';

export {MyComponent1, MyComponent2}
export default{
    install(Vue:any){
        Vue.component('MyComponent1', MyComponent);
        Vue.component('MyComponent2', MyComponent);
    }
}
```

This `index.ts` enables the programmer to bind in the lib by using `Vue.use(MyLib)` or by importing the needed componant manually:

```js
import {MyComponent1} from 'my-lib';
import {Vue, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components:{
        MyComponent1
    }
})
export default class Test extends Vue{}
```

Now my question is, if it has any inpact (e.g. on performance) to register all components in the install-method and use `Vue.use(MyLib)` or is it better to let the developer bind all needed components manually?

In addition to that for own components I have the same decission to register all components in `main.ts` or to import the component only where it is needed.

What is the recommanded approach?

Answer (score 0):

Performance will be the same, but by manually including the components instead of registering them, the dependency chain will be more explicit, and might allow for tree-shaking, making your packed code smaller.

Manually importing may also allow for lazy loading of the library components.